# How to get the number pairs on the left of a dataframegroupby? Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**I got a dataframeGroup by and then I print all pairs of groupby columns like:**

('br17', 'CBC') 
   instances  nbMaxVilles  Solver  Formulation        Temps_Calculs Optimal 
0      br17          10    CBC     fillMTZ  0.46119860999999673      39 
2      br17          10    CBC      fillDL    0.565562113999988      39 
('br17', 'Gurobi')
instances nbMaxVilles  Solver Formulation       Temps_Calculs Optimal 
1      br17          10  Gurobi     fillMTZ  0.4650516840000023      39 
3      br17          10  Gurobi      fillDL  0.5595316250000337      39 
('ft53', 'CBC')
instances nbMaxVilles Solver Formulation       Temps_Calculs Optimal 
6      ft53          13    CBC      fillDL  0.7997463710000261    1918 
4      ft53          13    CBC     fillMTZ   1.214644144000033    1918

if this is not clear, here is a picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0nyF.png)

and then I want to get all numbers pairs on the left such as:
[(0,2),(1,3),(6,4)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the groupby object is called grouper, try this -

```
[tuple(i) for i in grouper.indices.values()]
```

---

Another way -

```
grouper.apply(lambda x:x.index.tolist()).tolist()
```